# Align text in a TD with the bottom of an image in another TD

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why this text won't align with the bottom of the image:

Here is the example snippet:

```css
img {
  height: 80px;
  width: auto
}

.spacer {
  width: 30px;
}

h1 {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://unsplash.it/80" /></td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
    <td>
      <h1><b>KCFishFans.com</b></h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using tables?

Comment: I figured that was the best way to get space between the logo and text without having to use the cludgy "&nbsp".

Comment: If you want, I will make you an alternative example?

Comment: @MrBuggy - Sure.

Comment: I made you an alternative example below. I used flexbox for aligning the text with the bottom of the image and padding-left for the space between this two elements. In my opinion this is bether as a table layout and empty td for spaces :)

Comment: Did any answer helped you? Cheers

Answer (score 3):

`h1` has `margins` by default. You can remove these in your CSS.

```css
table h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://unsplash.it/80" style="height:80px; width:auto" /></td>
    <td style="width:30px"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
      <h1><b>KCFishFans.com</b></h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Clearly the snippet works, yet on my page it's not working.  :(

Comment: Can you inspect the page with the developer tools and see if the style is being applied / overridden?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my alternative solution for the layout and the space between the elements:

I would solve it with `flexbox` and a wrapper. For the space between the `img` and `h1` I would use `padding-left` in case of an empty `td` with a `width`. The advantage of this solution is, it is 100% aligned to the bottom of the img. With tables it isn't aligned 100% with the bottom of the image (I think because of the default line-height for the h1).

Here you have a **complete guide for flexbox**: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this helps.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.wrapper__image {
  height: 80px;
  width: auto
}

.wrapper__title {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="wrapper__image" src="https://unsplash.it/80">
  <h1 class="wrapper__title">KCFishFans.com</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: An alternative to setting a `line-height` on the heading, would be adding `align-items: baseline` to the wrapper -- also remove `align-self` from the heading

Comment: Nice input mate, I updated the snippet, please review it (I also removed the margin: 0 on the h1) :) @sol